# List Groovy constructors generated by Canonical and TupleConstructor

Tags: groovy

I have a deep hierarchy of POGOs (domain models) that make heavy use of `@Canonical` and `@TupleConstructor`. I now want to list out all the dynamically-generated constructors available for any one of my domain model classes.

I found this little Groovy gem:

```
println MyObject.metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique()
```

Which, when ran, beautifully prints a list of all the (defined and generated) methods for `MyObject`.

But, when I try to use this for constructors:

```
println MyObject.metaClass.constructors*.name.sort().unique()
```

...it just prints out:

```
[groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass$ExpandoMetaProperty@67c27493]
```

**How can I list out all the `@Canonical`- and `@TupleConstructor`-generated constructors (and their respective arguments) for any given class?**

More importantly (well not quite, but almost)...where is this documented?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `metaClass`:

```
MyObject.constructors​*.name.sort().unique()​​​​​
```

It should show just one value: `'MyObject'` (because all constructors have name `MyObject`)

Comment: Hmmm, thanks @yariash (+1) - however this just prints out `[com.me.myapp.MyObject]`, whereas I'm looking for a list of all constructors **and their respective arguments** (sorry, I'll clarify that back in the question). So I'd be looking for *something* like: `com.me.myapp.MyObject(String,Boolean,String,Fizz)`, etc. Also, is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Maybe if you remove `'.name.sort().unique()​​​​​'` part you will get what you want? Method  'name` just returns `MyObject`.

Comment: If I remove that and just use `println MyObject.constructors​*` then that gives a compiler error: `Groovy:expecting '}', found '*' @ line ...`. Any ideas?

Comment: `*` is spread operator, you have to remove it too. So just leave `MyObject.constructors`.